# Deleting item in Firemonkey TListView causes out of range exception

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I have a `TListView` with several items where each item has a corresponding "Remove" button.  The `TListView` has the following on button click event handler:

```
void __fastcall TSettingsCopyWizard_Fac::CopyToListViewButtonClick(TObject * const Sender,
      TListViewItem * const AItem, TListItemSimpleControl * const AObject)

{
    CopyToListView->BeginUpdate();
    CopyToListView->Items->Delete(AItem->Index);
    CopyToListView->EndUpdate();
}
```

When I try to delete an item, an "Arguments out of range" exception is thrown.  However, it is not on the `Delete` call, rather in `System.Generics.Collections` here:

```
procedure TListHelper.CheckItemRange(AIndex: Integer);
begin
  CheckItemRangeInline(AIndex); //this is the line that throws the exception
end;
```

Am I improperly deleting an item from my list view?  Or is there something else causing this issue?

Comment: You typically cannot destroy an object from inside an event handler that is associated with that object. Try using `TThread::Queue()` to delay the deletion until after the `OnButtonClick` handler has exited.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Unfortunately, `TThread::Queue` executed immediately, if CurrentThread == MainThread. I think it is more correct to use the timer.

Comment: @kami Having my button click handler enable a `TTimer` to delete the item worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is the right way to delete items in a ListView, so there must be something else wrong. As confirmation, here are some examples from Embarcadero that show this technique being used:

- [Tokyo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.TListView)
- [Berlin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Deleting_Strings)

This problem is corrected in new updates of C++ Builder. I tried it myself in Tokyo and Berlin, and can confirm that it works fine.